# How to declare multiple "attributes" in haskell?

Tags: haskell, project

i have to do a videclub project. My problem: when i create the data structures i cant declare more than 1 id,name or any "attribute"
.
Here is my code:

```
data Client = Client
  { _id        :: Int
  , _name      :: String
  , _lastname  :: String
  , _age       :: Int
  , _movies    :: [Movie]
  } deriving Show

data VideoClub = VideoClub
  { _id        :: Int
  , _name      :: String
  , _direccion :: String
  } deriving Show

data Movie= Movie
  { _id          :: Int
  , _title       :: String
  , _rented      :: Bool
  , _videoclub   :: VideoClub
  , _category    :: String
  } deriving Show
```

This is one of many problems that i have. Hope you can help me and give me some advices. Thank you.

Comment: This is actually a sore spot for Haskell, I believe there is an extension in the works for GHC that is either in 7.10 or will be in 8.0 that allows for overloaded record fields.  The best I can say is to use the `lens` library (it looks like you are already) and make `HasId` and `HasAttribute` typeclasses with your types implementing them as necessary with `_clientId`, `_videoClubId` etc.  It's gross, I know, but there may be some handy template haskell in `lens` for generating that if you use the right naming scheme.

Comment: [Found it](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.13/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makeFields), if you use `makeFields` (so long as your types are all declared in the same module) then it'll take care of that boilerplate for you.

Comment: You're right it can be annoying that you can't use names twice. But at the same time, using different names makes it very explicit that the functions are also different. I tend to prefix my field names with something referring to the type, i.e. `clId`, `clName`, `vcId`, `vcName`,`movId`,`movName` etc. It's not pretty but I do actually feel like it makes more explicit which type your functions work on etc.

Comment: Thank you both, i already did it (rename the attributes). But there's another problem, im trying to do a function: movieCopies -> this function return a list of movies with how much copies has the videoclub. i.e : "Figth Club" 3 copies. I need so much help with this project.

Comment: Then you should ask that as well, as a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option to consider is to have an `Identified` type:

```
data Identified a = Identified
  { _id  :: Int
  , _val :: a
  } deriving (Functor, Show)

instance Comonad Identified where
  extract = _val
  duplicate v = Identified (_id v) v

data Client = Client
  { _name      :: String
  , _lastname  :: String
  , _age       :: Int
  , _movies    :: [Movie]
  } deriving Show
```

Then you can choose to use `Client` or `Identified Client` as appropriate throughout your source (and similarly for your other types). This also makes things like `IntMap Client` more sane: one need not preserve the invariant that the `Client`'s `_id` match its key in the map.

Comment: This is a great strategy, especially for dealing with cases where you don't know the identifier a priori, like creating a record in a database with an auto-incremented PK or POSTing to create a RESTful resource that will be assigned an id by the server. That said, I'm not sure what the `Comonad` interface buys you aside from `extract`? Is there a use case for `duplicate` or working with coKleisli arrows via cobind?

Comment: I vaguely recall reading a blog post some time ago that claimed to get some leverage from dealing with a database IDs in a comonadic way, though my Google-fu seems to be lacking -- I can't find it again -- and I don't recall the details of the leverage well enough to reproduce them here, either. So I guess this is the encouraging version of FUD.

Comment: Thanks great answer, but how can i implement this ?. I need to import some libs rigth ? (i havent worked with monads or comonads)

Comment: I'll buy it for a dollar :)

Comment: @AleMaier The `Comonad` interface is a nice-to-have. You can just use the `_id` and `_val` fields like any other record. With it, you have `extract :: Identified Client -> Client` to extract the Client from its Identified wrapper. As the definition shows, this is equivalent to `_val`.

Comment: @DanielWagner btw with lenses and `makeClassy`, you can use the same lenses to interact with both `Identified Client` and `Client`, so you can just say `view name` in either case, which seems very nice.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs so with this how can i do this : 
"Movie number 1: Fight Club" 
"Movie number 2: Inception"

.. I need to display the number from the movie, that number i took it from its id, the only way i found.

Comment: `data Movie = Movie String; [Identified 1 (Movie "Fight Club"), Identified 2 (Movie "Inception")]`

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.